# Join and add columns in one go

Tags: r, data.table

**Background**

I am fairly new to the `data.table` library and currently learning to use it efficiently. What I have here, are two tables and I want to aggregate the second one first, then merge it with the first one and modify a column in the joined table. Ideally (and for my understanding) in one go.

**Package version**

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
# Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

# other attached packages:
# [1] data.table_1.9.4

# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] chron_2.3-45  plyr_1.8.1    Rcpp_0.11.2   reshape2_1.4  stringr_0.6.2
# [6] tools_3.1.0
```

**Code**

What I have tried can be seen in this minimal example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT1 <- data.table(id = LETTERS[1:4], x = rnorm(4), key = "id")
DT2 <- data.table(id = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3), y = 1:12, z = rep(1, 12), key = "id")
DT1[DT2[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = "id"]] # simple join works fine
#    id         x  y z
# 1:  A -0.6264538  2 1
# 2:  B  0.1836433  5 1
# 3:  C -0.8356286  8 1
# 4:  D  1.5952808 11 1

# however, adding a 'j' argument does not work
DT1[DT2[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = "id"], x := -x] # (1)

# in fact the above statement changes the 'x' column in 'DT1':
DT1
#    id          x
# 1:  A  0.6264538
# 2:  B -0.1836433
# 3:  C  0.8356286
# 4:  D -1.5952808
```

I guess that this has something to do with the smart way how `data.table` handles data (and does not make copies unless needed, so calling by reference). Hence, the following code works:

```
DT3 <- copy(DT1[DT2[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = "id"]])[, x := -x]
(DT4 <- DT1[DT2[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = "id"]][, x := -x]) # (2)
#    id          x  y z
# 1:  A -0.6264538  2 1
# 2:  B  0.1836433  5 1
# 3:  C -0.8356286  8 1
# 4:  D  1.5952808 11 1
identical(DT3, DT4)
# [1] TRUE
```

**Questions**

1. What is the 'best' way of doing it? 'Best' in terms of time and memory used?
2. What would be the conceptual way of doing it? So in other words, what would be the series of commands, Matt Dowle (the package maintainer) would use?
3. Why does `(1)` not work while `(2)` works as expected?

Comment: We should always ask ourselves, WWMDD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your current implementation (1)

```
DT1[DT2[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = "id"], x := -x] # (1)
```

is that your are modifying `DT1` by reference with `x:=-x`, the join with `DT2[,...]` is not actually assigned.

What you want is (4)

```
 DT3 <- DT1[DT2[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = "id"]][, x := -x]
```

Here, an extra call to `[` on the joined dataset means that you are assigning `x:=-x` in the newly created data.table.

There is no need for the explicit copy unless you really need to.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was assuming that it has something to do with changing slots by reference. Just out of curiousity: is the `data.table` copied in case (2) as well?

Comment: @thothal A new data.table is created with `DT1[DT2[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = "id"]]`, wrapping that in copy will copy this new datatable (to the best of my knowledge)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd tackle this with dplyr:

```
library("dplyr")

set.seed(1)
DT1 <- data_frame(id = LETTERS[1:4], x = rnorm(4), key = "id")
DT2 <- data_frame(id = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3), y = 1:12, z = rep(1, 12), key = "id")

DT2 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean), y:z) %>%
  left_join(DT1) %>% 
  mutate(x = -x)
```

(assuming that I've correctly interpreted your data.table code)

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. Actually, that was my first code. However, I just wanted to explore the `data.table` option to learn something new.